# How to grab parent/child outside of SVG element?

Tags: javascript, loops, svg, popup, maps

I've working on something organized as follows:

- Parent

  - A bunch of children

    - Element A inside one of those children
- Parent

  - SVG element

    - Path inside SVG element, that when clicked should add a class to Element A (.state-info)

Essentially, when a user clicks on a certain state on the map, a class name specific to that state is added on a child of the ensuing popup window (#map-popup). I have a loop below where I would eventually add an if/then for each state. That console log I have in there is working, but the class is not being added. I've also gotten the code to work just fine with a parent of the clicked path within the same SVG element.

I'm pretty new to JS and the ".SVGGeometryElement" below is kind of just me trying random stuff I googled. Also I (clearly, probably) don't have the world's best grasp of how all the hierarchal stuff works between various parents/ children.

Thank you so much to anyone who can help!

```
    var stateWrap = document.querySelectorAll('.map-click path');
                
    for (var i = 0; i < stateWrap.length; i++) {
                            
       stateWrap[i];
                            
       if (stateWrap[i].classList.contains('colorado')) {
                                
        stateWrap[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('hi');
            this.closest.SVGGeometryElement.parentNode.closest('#map-popup .state-info').classList.add('co-popup');
        });
    }
```

EDIT: Here's an abbreviated version of the HTML/ SVG stuff I'm working with. Below that is a script I have in here to add the "map-click" class to the relevant map containers, incase that's affecting things.

```
<main class="site-main post-77 page type-page status-publish hentry" role="main">
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            Map Test
        </h1>
    </header>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div data-elementor-type="wp-page" data-elementor-id="77" class="elementor elementor-77" data-elementor-settings="[]">
            <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-202d650 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="202d650" data-element_type="section">
                    <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                        <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-5e3fddc" data-id="5e3fddc" data-element_type="column">
                            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4006520 elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="4006520" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                                    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                        <div class="elementor-shortcode">
                                            <div id="usmapwrapper-t" style="opacity: 1;">
                                                <div id="usmapbase-t">
                                                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 700 440" xml:space="preserve">
                                                    <g class="map-click">
                                                        
                                                        <!-- COLORADO MAP PATH -->
                                                        
                                                        <path id="usmapvt_6" class="colorado" fill="#E0F3FF" stroke="#6B8B9E" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M280.82,193.56c0.121-9.452,0.218-16.314,0.218-16.314c-3.884-0.005-12.009-0.401-22.128-1.021v0v0c-17.95-1.098-42.199-2.902-60.364-4.489c-2,18.667-4.401,41.61-6.753,64.075c26.211,2.673,52.117,4.443,76.068,5.528c4.237,0.193,8.413,0.362,12.519,0.513C280.369,231.215,280.624,208.954,280.82,193.56z" cursor="pointer" style="fill: rgb(224, 243, 255);"></path>
                                                    </g>
                                                    <g id="usvisns-t" class="map-click" fill="#666666">
                                                        <text id="usvnvt_6" class="colorado" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 228 211)" font-size="14" cursor="pointer">
                                                            CO
                                                        </text>
                                                    </g>
                                                </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-tags"></div>
    </div>
    <section id="comments" class="comments-area"></section>
</main>


<!-- POPUP IS IN HERE -->
<div class="dialog-widget dialog-lightbox-widget dialog-type-buttons dialog-type-lightbox elementor-popup-modal" id="elementor-popup-modal-83" style="">
    <div class="dialog-widget-content dialog-lightbox-widget-content animated">
        <div class="dialog-header dialog-lightbox-header"></div>
        <div class="dialog-message dialog-lightbox-message">
            <div data-elementor-type="popup" data-elementor-id="83" class="elementor elementor-83 elementor-location-popup" data-elementor-settings="{&quot;open_selector&quot;:&quot;.map-click&quot;,&quot;triggers&quot;:[],&quot;timing&quot;:[]}" style="display: block;">
                <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                    <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-216c580 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="216c580" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                            <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-bc55a08" data-id="bc55a08" data-element_type="column">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                    
                                    <!-- MAP POPUP DIV -->
                                    
                                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6fca46c elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="6fca46c" data-element_type="widget" id="map-popup" data-widget_type="html.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <div class="state-info">
                                                #
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-761c48b state-cert-popup elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="761c48b" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                            <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-c8eca70" data-id="c8eca70" data-element_type="column">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dialog-buttons-wrapper dialog-lightbox-buttons-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="dialog-close-button dialog-lightbox-close-button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    /* Add class to states and abbreviations */
    var mapContainer = document.querySelector('#usmapbase-t g:nth-child(2)');
    var mapContainer2 = document.querySelector('#usvisns-t');
    
    mapContainer.classList.add('map-click');
    mapContainer2.classList.add('map-click');
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide some of your HTML/SVG code?

Answer (score 1):

To give a proper answer, we would really need to see what your actual HTML and SVG looked like.  So I'm guessing a bit here.  The following code may need some modifications depending on your exact page content.

I think your JS would need to look something like the following:

```
var mapPopup = document.getElementById("map-popup");
var stateWrap = document.querySelectorAll('.map-click path');

// Remember the last state class that we added
var lastStateClass = '';

// forEach is just a nicer way of doing your for loop
stateWrap.forEach(function(stateElement) {
  // Add a click listener to each stateWrap element
  stateElement.addEventListener("click", handleStateClick);
});


function handleStateClick(event) {
  // First we need to remove any state class we might have
  // added in a previous click. Other wise they will just
  // accumulate and interfere with one another.
  mapPopup.classList.remove(lastStateClass);
  lastStateClass == '';

  // The clicked state element will be in event.target
  // If we clicked on a state, then set a new state class
  if (event.target.classList.contains('colorado')) {
    lastStateClass = 'co-popup';
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains('california')) {
    lastStateClass = 'ca-popup';
  } // else if (etc)

  // If a new state was clicked, update the map-popul
  if (lastStateClass != '') {
    mapPopup.classList.add(lastStateClass);
  }
}
```

However having a big `if then` block for all fifty states is not the most elegant solution, so I would do something more like the following.

```
var mapPopup = document.getElementById("map-popup");
var stateWrap = document.querySelectorAll('.map-click path');

// Remember mapPopup's default class attribute
// We are going to use this as an alternative was to remove the state
// class we add. Pick which of the two approaches you prefer.
var mapPopupOriginalClassAttr = mapPopup.getAttribute('class');

// Instead of a big if/then block, we will lookup the state class
// using a map object
var stateToInfoClass = {
  'colorado': 'co-popup',
  'california': 'ca-popup'
  // etc
};

// forEach is just a nicer way of doing your for loop
stateWrap.forEach(function(stateElement) {
  // Add a click listener to each stateWrap element
  stateElement.addEventListener("click", handleStateClick);
});

function handleStateClick(event) {
  // First we need to remove any state class we might have
  // added in a previous click. This time we do that by just
  // resetting the class attribute to its original value.
  mapPopup.setAttribute("class", mapPopupOriginalClassAttr);

  // Which popup class corresponds to this state name?
  var popupClass = findStateName(stateElem);
  // Add the class to the popup
  mapPopup.classList.add(popupClass);
});

// Search through stateToInfoClass looking for a state name
// that matches a class name in this stateElem's classList.
function findStateName(stateElem) {
   // For every entry in the stateToInfoClass object
   for (item in stateToInfoClass) {
     // item may be a built in object property like 'length'
     // hasOwnProperty filters those out
     if (stateToInfoClass.hasOwnProperty(item) {
       // Does this state name appear in stateItem's classList?
       if (stateElem.classList.contains(item) {
         // Yes! Return the corresponding state class name
         return stateToInfoClass[item];
     }
  }
  // No state name found. How did this happen?
  return '';
}
```

The above code assumes that there could be more than one class name in your state class attribute. Eg. `class="some-other-class colorado"`.  If that's wrong, and the class contains only the state name (`class="colorado"`), then you could get rid of the `findStateName()` function and change

```
var popupClass = findStateName(stateElem);
```

to

```
var popupClass = stateElem.getAttribute("class");
```

You could simplify things further if the class for your popup used the full state name instead of the abbreviation.  For example, if the class was `colorado-popup` instead of `co-popup`), then you could just do:

```
function handleStateClick(event) {
  // First we need to remove any state class we might have
  // added in a previous click. This time we do that by just
  // resetting the class attribute to its original value.
  mapPopup.setAttribute("class", mapPopupOriginalClassAttr);

  // Add the class to the popup
  mapPopup.classList.add(stateElem.getAttribute("class") + '-popup');
});
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so awesome and thorough. I'll give this a try tomorrow - traveling so just wanted to pop in with my gratitude until I can give it a go.

Comment: Hey! Finally was able got back to this project. I still wasn't seeing that "co-popup" class get added, so I tossed my code up top. It's Wordpress/ Elementor/ some map plugin so I tried to cut out anything excessively long that wasn't relevant (including states other than CO). Thank you!

Comment: The two `mapContainer.classList.add('map-click');` lines are not doing anything because the elements they are modifying already have `class="map-click"`. Did you paste the wrong code perhaps?

Comment: Hey Paul, they actually weren't in there until that script was added, so that's how they got in there :)

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/rxmL3f7b/1/

Answer (score 0):

In this example I add an event listener to the `<ul>`. So, I just need one event listener for multiple elements. On click I test to see if the target was a `<rect>`. If so, I change the class name for the element itself, for the list and the header.

Could this be used as an example in your case?

```js
var ul01 = document.getElementById('ul01');

ul01.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'rect'){
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
    e.target.closest('ul').classList.toggle('square');
    e.target.closest('#div01').querySelector('h2').classList.toggle('abc');
  }
});
```

```css
rect.selected {
  fill: red;
}

ul.square {
  list-style-type: square;
}

h2.abc {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="div01">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <ul id="ul01">
    <li>Item <svg width="20" height="20"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="navy"></svg></li>
    <li>Item <svg width="20" height="20"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="navy"></svg></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot in the AM and see how things are looking. Worst case I will come back with the HTML/ SVG code!